# Expected number of leaf nodes in some theoretical graph models

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, spectral-graph-theory, network

If a leaf node of a graph refers to a node having the degree of 1, how can one compute the expected number of leaf nodes of:

(A) a random graph (e.g., Erdos-Renyi graph),

(B) a small-world graph (e.g., Watts and Stragatz model) and

(C) a scale-free graph (e.g., Barabasi model)?

Assume I know the parameters related to the construction of the graphs (e.g., knowing the size of the graph, edge probability in ER graph, rewiring probability of small-world graph, the preferential attachment probability etc).

If any such results have been published somewhere, please point me to the right resources as well.